# How to perform CONNECT HTTP request to a Host on specific port?

Tags: http, httprequest, connect, httpresponse

How can I perform `CONNECT HTTP` requests to a Host on specific port?

If there is a tool to achieve this I'd appreciate mentioning it.

Comment: Context? Langugage? Technology?

Comment: Thanks. In Perl. Actually it's an Open Proxy that I setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use telnet to send HTTP requests and accomplish connection to hosts.

For example, start with the following cmd through shell:

```
telnet www.server.com 80
```

Then, after connection has established you may send HTTP requests.

[Read more](http://blog.tonycode.com/tech-stuff/http-notes/making-http-requests-via-telnet)